# Why my geocode cannot show the address

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocode, street-address, postal-code

```
var geocoder, map, point, fmtAdd, marker;

function mapLoad() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeControl: false, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
address="W3 6BY";
if(address){geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, geocodeResult);}
else{alert("Postcode Incorrect");window.close();}
}

function geocodeResult(results, status) {
if (status == 'OK' && results.length > 0) {
    point=results[0].geometry.location;
    map.setCenter(point);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: point, draggable: true});
    geocoder.geocode({latLng:point},function(results, status){
          if(status == 'OK') {
            if(results.length == 0) {
            fmtAdd = 'None';
            } else {
            fmtAdd = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
          } else {
            fmtAdd = 'Error';
          }
          alert(fmtAdd); // shows the address
        });
          alert(fmtAdd); // says undefined;
} else {
  alert("Error: " + status);
}
}
mapLoad();
```

I want to show the formatted address from user's input who are in the UK. But I don't understand why the second alert is undefined? Didn't I defined the variable "fmtAdd" at the first line?

Comment: You should tag your question with the programming language you are using and the google maps api tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "second" alert is actually your first alert since it is executed first (`geocode()` is non blocking - it returns immediately).
At that point you "defined" `fmtAdd`, but you didn't initialize it.

```
var foo; alert(foo);
```

alerts `undefined`.

---

answering comment:

> I thought it was a global variable, and once the geocode give
>   an value to it, I can retrieve that value even out of the geocode
>   function.

This is correct. The variable is initialized once the callback function passed to `geocode()` sets a value to it. And exactly that happens. **After** that "event" you can retrieve the value from your global variable also outside of your function.

The problem here is that you're trying to retrieve the value from `fmtAddr` **before** your callback function has completed (or is even called).
This is because `geocode()` is non-blocking. This means that it returns immediately, this is why you pass a *callback function* to `geocode()`.

### What happens

referring to this part of the code:

```
geocoder.geocode({ latLng: point }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
        if (results.length == 0) {
            fmtAdd = 'None';
        } else {
            fmtAdd = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
    } else {
        fmtAdd = 'Error';
    }
    alert(fmtAdd); // shows the address
});
alert(fmtAdd); // says undefined;
```

In chronological order:

1. you call `geocode()`, passing a callback to it
2. `geocode()` starts an asynchronous request to the google servers and returns immediately
3. `alert(fmtAdd); // says undefined;`
4. the asynchronous request completes and calls your callback function
5. your callback function sets `fmtAddr`

## what you need to do

execute your application in the correct order:

- Create a function which does whatever you want to do with the formatted address.
- Call this function from your callback. That is, after you set `fmtAdd`

(actually better would be to pass the formatted address directly to this function as a parameter, without using global variables)

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand why the address is not saved in the variable fmtAdd, I thought it was a global variable, and once the geocode give an value to it, I can retrieve that value even out of the geocode function.